# useAsync() hook does not get called when the component is reloaded

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a main component MainComp which calls a Child Component ChildComp like so:

```
<ChildComp data={data}>
```

This is ChildComp:

```
export const ChildComp = (props: any) => {
    console.log("#1");
    const { value, loading, error } = useAsync(async (): Promise<any> => {  
        console.log("#2");
        const response = await fetch(<some url>);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }, []);
}

if (loading) {
    // return
} else if (error) {
    // return 
}

return value;
```

When the child component is invoked initially when the page loads, everything works correctly. However, when the props to the child component is changed, the component is reloaded but useAsync hook is not invoked. As a result, I get #1 printed on the console but not #2.

Any idea how I can invoke useAsync() again when the component is reloaded because the props change? The URL inside fetch changes according to the props that are being passed and hence needs to be called each time there is a change.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add the url to the dependency array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the right dependencies to the `useAsync()` hook:

```js
 const { value, loading, error } = useAsync(async (): Promise<any> => {  
    // ...
 }, []); // <---- Indicate here the props/url upon which change you want to re-fetch data
```